# How can a django forms.CharField generate a required input?

Tags: python, django

I'm a new pie to `django` and trying to use `forms.CharField` to generate a required input.

By default, a `forms.CharField` is translated as:

```
<input id="id_mail_to" name="mail_to" type="text" />
```

But I want a:

```
<input id="id_mail_to" name="mail_to" type="text" required/>
```

How can I get that?

Comment: You want to make `mail_to` field compulsory ?

Comment: @Fledgling In this case, yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [attrs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs)

Try this,

```
mail_to=forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'required': "required"}))
```

You can see this,

```
<input id="id_mail_to" name="mail_to" required="required" type="text">
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6rtuk/)

Comment: It works, thanks. `require=True` is not needed in technical, but maybe it making the setting more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in forms.py

```
mail_to= forms.CharField(required=True, label="mail to")
```

Comment: `required=True` is setted as default, but it will not generate a input required.